# n-Records to reducer after Shuffle and Sort

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I would like to move only the first 10 records of the output after sort/shuffle to the reducer. Is this possible?

The reason is this: I am to find the least 10 items with the largest count in a file. However, I know that the results of the mapping phase will be arrive at the reducer already sorted. Hence, instead of sorting in the mappers, I'd like to just pass only the first 10 lines after 'shuffle and sort' to the reducer. this will allow the reducer sort only a subset of the original record.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You can achieve the same in reducer itself...

Comment: That means all the records will get to the reducer. I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing a custom `Combiner` for the job.

The different stages in the `MapReduce` job are:

```
Mapper -> Partitioner -> Sorting -> Combiner -> Reducer.
```

Now `Combiner` logic only read the first 10 (n) records and discord all the other. The `Reducer` will receive only 10 records from each `Mapper`/`Combiner`.

---

Comment provided by `@K246`:

> From haodop definitive guide (4th ed) : Before it writes to disk, the thread first divides the data into partitions corresponding to the reducers that they will ultimately be sent to. Within each partition, the background thread performs an in-memory sort by key, and if there is a combiner function, it is run on the output of the sort.

Comment: I checked this, I believe the correct order is: Mapper ->  Combiner -> Sorting -> Partitioner ->Reducer.

Comment: @oma07 Check the question description: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27790601/2254048.

Comment: @oma07 Here is the another link for the same: [Shuffle and Sort ](http://hadoopinterviews.com/shuffle-sort-sns-key-understand-magic/). Please share you found it other way round.

Comment: YoungHobbit is right. Think about this. Logic of combiner and reducer is often same. Like reducer, combiner also works on the values of the same key. combiner can't be get all values corresponding to same key unless the key,value output of mapper is portioned. Which means partition has to come before combiner.

Comment: From haodop definitive guide (4th ed): 

"Before it writes to disk, the thread first divides the data into partitions corresponding to the reducers that they will ultimately be sent to. Within each partition, the background thread performs an in-memory sort by key, and if there is a combiner function, it is run on the output of the sort. "

Answer (score 0):

When you say least 10 in the file...Is it for each mapper or for the entire input.
If for each mapper, then you have to aggregate the again at reducer from all mappers. Then as @YoungHobbit pointed out, Combiner will do the work.

If you need least 10 from entire input file, then I think, you need to handle it with a single reducer and output accordingly.

Also, you said in the last line, that reducer will sort only subset. Do you mean you are sorting again in Reducer or that some logic is performed in reducer for only subset of the input.

Comment: the least 10 from each mapper after sort and shufle. And yes, i will be sorting again to obtain the overall least 10 from the reducer.

Comment: Ok. So the combiner as mentioned below would be the best option, as it happens similar to reducer and before the reducer. Also, since finding least 10 logic can be achieved using combiner, as it is an algebraic function. Combiner runs before the merging process(collection map output from different nodes)